# dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold does not run correctly from code

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am trying to create a model from an existing database from c# code.
The statements I use are exactly the ones given in the Microsoft documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli
and I am simply executing them via a process created in c# code.

When executed directly from the command line the entity model is generated correctly for both the db context and the classes for the entities.

When executed via a process from VS2022 the statements run correctly without reporting an error but only the db context is generated, and no classes for the entities are created.

If you run in an empty folder the  statements as generated by the code, ie:

```
dotnet new console
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
dotnet add package  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=***.***.***.***;User Id=******;Password=*********" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Model -f -v
```

and examini the result folder, in the Model folder you will find the dbcontext AND all the entities definitions for the database.

I am confused at this point, and would like to hear from anybody who might have an idea of what is happening.

Comment: I would recommend you to remove your connection string information... ip as well as password (especially incase of a production database and sensitive data)

Comment: Hi Dominik,The server and the database are not production, they have just been set up for this tets